# A vector space contains $\mathbb{R}$ but have scalar product defined differently than vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question, real-numbers

Suppose we have a vector space with the underlying field being $\mathbb{R}$. Just out of curiosity, what are some examples of vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$, where $\mathbb{R} \subsetneq V$, but these vectors $\mathbb{R}$ are different from the scalars $\mathbb{R}$?

To be precise, how can we define a multiplication $\cdot_{v}$ between vectors in V s.t. $x \cdot_{v} y$ = $xy$ when $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ , and for a linear operator $L$ on $V$ we have $c L(x) \neq L(c \cdot_{v} x)$ for some $c \in R, x \in V$?

Additionally, it would be nice if $\cdot_{v}$ satisfies some property, say would it be possible for V to be an algebra, or to be additionally a field? If this is impossible, it would still be nice if $\cdot_{v}$ satisfies some other property.

I guess we can define $x \cdot_{v} y = 0$ for $x \vee y \notin \mathbb{R}$? Are there more examples that are nice? I'm sorry that I do not know much about abstract algebra, but I would love to see if there are nice constructions.

Comment: If you define $x\cdot_v y=0$ if $x$ or $y$ is not in the copy of $\mathbb R$ that’s inside of $V$, then it will not be distributive over vector addition: taking $x\in V$ such that neither $x$ nor $x+1$ is in the copy of $\mathbb R$ in $V$, we have $2\cdot_v(x+1) = 0$ but $2\cdot_v x + 2\cdot_v 1 = 0 + 1 = 1$ (where here $1$ denotes the $1$ in the copy of $\mathbb R$ in $V$, not the scalar $1$).

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi Thank you. I cannot think of other trivial examples, do you have any?

Comment: I’m not coming up with any off the top of my head. The requirement that $x\cdot_v y=xy$ for $x,y$ in the copy of $\mathbb R$ in $V$ seems to make this a little tricky.

Comment: Well, here’s something: let $V$ be the vector space of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, and define the product of $f(t),g(t)\in V$ to be the constant function $f\cdot_v g = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$. Then $V$ contains a copy of $\mathbb R$ in the form of the constant functions and multiplication on this set agrees with normal multiplication in $\mathbb R$, but if $f(t)=a\neq 0$ is constant and $g(t)$ is non-constant, then the scalar-vector product $ag(t)$ will not be the same as $f\cdot_v g(t)$ (since the former is not constant whereas the latter is). But this may not be very well-behaved.

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi Thank you for the example. Would you mind also giving an explicit example of a linear operator as described above in the question?

Comment: With @KenanskiBowspleefi's example, take the linear operator $L(f)(t) = tf(t)$.

Comment: Just extend $1_R$ to a basis $\{e_1:=1_R, e_2, e_3, ..., e_n\}$ of $V$ and define $\cdot_v$ as the product of their first components, i.e. $\sum a_i e_i \cdot_v \sum b_i e_i := (a_1b_1)e_1$. Works for infinite dimensions too.

Comment: Of course this is impossible for a unital algebra structure on $V$ if by "the" copy of $\mathbb R$ inside $V$ we mean (as one usually does) the span $\mathbb R 1_V$ of the unit element $1_V$. Note the construction in my previous comment has no unit element (if the dimension is $\ge 2$ --- otherwise it's not what you want anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Two things are odd in your question:

1. It is not clear what kind of "inclusion" is meant by $\mathbb R \subsetneq V$. If $V$ is any $\mathbb R$-vector space and $v \neq 0$ is any vector in it, then I can identify the one-dimensional space spanned by $v$ with $\mathbb R$ (and that's an inclusion of $\mathbb R$-vector spaces). Unless there is already more structure on $V$, there is no more natural or canonical subspace of it that one would normally identify with $\mathbb R$.
2. You ask about possible multiplications $\cdot_v$ on $V$ which, when restricted to the "$\mathbb R$" of above, identify with the standard multiplication but for a "linear operator $L$ on $V$" (i.e. presumably $L \in End_\mathbb R(V)$) "we have $cL(x) \neq L(c\cdot_v x)$ for some $c \in \mathbb R, v \in V$". But if we denote the scalar multiplication of $V$ by $cv$ (which I assume is what you do here), then $L$ being *linear* means $cL(x) = L(cx)$, and hence the condition you want is expressed equivalently, but easier, by saying that there are $c \in \mathbb R, w \in V$ with $c \cdot_v w \ \neq cw$ (take either $w=v$ or $w=L(v)$ in your condition). Why bring up linear maps here?

That all being said, there are tons of such maps, already if $V$ is of finite dimension. If $V$ has dimension $n$, then just the bilinear maps $V \times V \rightarrow V$ form a vector space of dimension $n^3$. If you demand commutativity, you half the dimension, and if you demand e.g. associativity, you get a subvariety that is no longer a subspace but still of dimension bigger than $2$. And the constraint that on the subspace called $\mathbb R$ it identifies with a given multiplication just lowers the dimension by $1$, so we still have some leeway.

In fact, let $e_1 \in V$ the element that corresponds to $1_\mathbb R$ in your "inclusion" $\mathbb R \subsetneq V$, and extend it to a basis $e_1, ... e_n$. For any such choice of basis (of which there are ... plenty), you can identify $V$ with $\mathbb R \times ... \times \mathbb R$, the $n$-fold direct product of $\mathbb R$ with itself, which has a natural ring structure, and that gives you an example of a multiplication like the one you want, which is bilinear, associative, and commutative. (You could even go further and compose any of those maps with a projection to the first, or the first two, or the first ... factors, and possibly more, and not lose any of the mentioned properties.)

But one thing you cannot have: For any *given* algebra structure on $V$ (say we call it $A$, with multiplication $\cdot_A$) which has a unit $1_A$, it is guaranteed by definitions that $cv = (c1_A)\cdot_A v = c\cdot_A v$ i.e. you cannot identify the subspace spanned by $1_A$ with $\mathbb R$, and then have some vector where the multiplication does not agree with the scalar multiplication. That is a bummer because: If, for any such algebra, people write that there is a standard inclusion $\mathbb R \subset V=A$, they usually do mean exactly *that* inclusion, i.e. the copy of $\mathbb R$ in $V=A$ is the one spanned by $A$'s unit element, $\mathbb R 1_A$.

In fact, since your "inclusion" $\mathbb R \subset V$ with the property $v \cdot_v w = vw$ for $v,w \in \mathbb R$ makes the element $1_\mathbb R$ an idempotent, but by the previous paragraph not a unit of the full algebra, you know this much about all possible "multiplication" maps that answer your question: They have non-trivial idempotents and hence non-trivial zero divisors. In particular, they cannot give the structure of a domain, let alone skew field or fields.

---

Final Note: All this works over any field instead of $\mathbb R$, and also one can adapt the ideas to infinite dimensions, where after all  there is more leeway. In fact, Keenan Bowspleefi's example from the comment is similar in spirit and provides us with even more examples: You can take any bilinear form $b: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ on your vector space, which on the chosen "$\mathbb R$" subspace identifies with the normal multiplication (equivalently, you have to norm it to $b(1_{\mathbb R}, 1_{\mathbb R}) =1$). Then you take the composed map $v \cdot_v w := (b(v,w)) 1_\mathbb R$ (with scalar multiplication on the right). Obviously this cannot agree with scalar multiplication on any vector outside of your "$\mathbb R$". Note however that while this map is still bilinear, it has no reason to be associative, and in Keenan's example indeed is not.